# How can I search for the fastest update server on the command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line)

This is easily done through the GUI, but can it be done from the command line? I have a BASH script for installing systems from the minimal ISO, and it would be nice to have the option of hunting down the fastest mirror before installing tons of packages.