# "fastestmirror" like plugin for Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, repository, mirrors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me)

Are there any plugins for apt like the fastestmirror on e.g.: Fedora?

So that the selected repo mirror for Ubuntu is always fast (because the plugin always uses the fastest server)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the option to find the fastest Server in Synaptic. You can also do that by hand in a script. That script would for instances ping all mirrors in the list, selecting the fastest and then edit the sources.list accordingly.

There was a question about this recently. Will look for it. Please stand by.

Edit:

[Lenkenstyen's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me) answers the gui-part and for newer versions the console part.

As for the [console part](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line) on older versions of ubuntu you could consulte the link postet earlier in this sentence.