# How to lower wait time for repository updates

Tags: apt, updates

When doing a `aptitude update` / `apt-get update` or using the Update Manager to update sometimes I get to a repository link that takes too long. The percent does not end and it takes quite a while before it ignores it.

How can I lower the time so that if a particular repository takes more than 10 seconds to connect or finish it should ignore it and move the following ones. Here is an image explaining the problem:

[image]

It is trying to connect to **archive.ubuntu.com** but since it is taking too long it just sits there for at least 3 to 5 minutes (Haven't measured the time) and then it shows as ignored and moves to the following. I wish to change that to seconds instead of minutes.

Comment: Try using a different mirror.  The default ones for each reason often aren't the fastest.  For example the default mirror for China  would always have me waiting 5-15 minutes to update my repositories.  Changed it to a faster one and now it takes about 30 seconds.

Comment: @adempewolff Would you be able/willing to write an answer containing the information in that comment, and also showing (including both a description and an image) how to change the mirror in the Software Sources?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> How can I lower the time so that if a particular repository takes more than 10 seconds to connect or finish it should ignore it and move the following ones?

Mirrors are one option, as @adempewolff explained. Let me give you a direct answer though:

#### Setting apt-get connection timeouts

You can control these timeouts via the following `apt.conf` options:

```
  Acquire::http::Timeout "10";
  Acquire::ftp::Timeout "10";
```

Note that this only applies to connection timeouts, NOT "finish time" timeouts, i.e. if it connects within 10 seconds, it will continue to download a 100MB package even if it's at 1 KB/second :)

To implement these options, simply create a conf file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`; suppose we call it `99timeout`.

- Press `Alt+F2`, type `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99timeout`
- Type/paste the above lines, with your choice of timeout in seconds
- Save and exit.
- Now try `sudo apt-get update`

---

#### And the terminal-addict's "find best server" hack!

Expanded and moved as an answer to [this more appropriate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/141536/58612)

---

#### Additional apt-get conf options that you can try to tweak

- `Acquire::Queue-Mode`: Queuing mode; Queue-Mode can be one of `host` or `access` which determines how APT parallelizes outgoing connections.  `host` means that one connection per target host will be opened, `access` means that one connection per URI type will be opened.
- `Acquire::Retries`: Number of retries to perform. If this is non-zero APT will retry failed files the given number of times.
- `Acquire::http::Dl-Limit`: accepts integer values in kilobytes, to throttle download speed and not slow down your browsing/email/etc. when updating. The default value is 0 which deactivates the limit and tries uses as much as possible of the bandwidth. If enabled, it will disable `apt-get`'s parallel downloading feature.
- Dig through `man apt.conf` if you think something else might help!

Comment: Is there a way to implement a "finish time" timeout?  I know in my case (and I'm guessing in the OP's case as he mentions the percentage taking forever, implying it's already connected) its usually not a matter of the connection timing out, it's just a problem of the connection being painstakingly slow (like 1 kb/s slow).

Comment: I wish I could give you +2 for that second part; I've been wondering how to test for the fastest servers from the terminal for a loong time.

Comment: Thanks @adempewolff, I actually want to write/modify something like `netselect-apt` for Ubuntu so it's all in the executable. Re your finish time question, I don't think there is a way at the apt-conf level. But `man apt.conf`, and see "The Acquire Group", specifically *Queue-Mode* and *Retries* which may be helpful.

Comment: I accepted but for the "Best server hack" I gave you a +1 on that other answer and this one. It is very smart.

Comment: To automate this within a Docker container inside Dockerfile: `RUN echo 'Acquire::http::Timeout "100";\nAcquire::ftp::Timeout "100";\nAcquire::Retries "10";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99timeout`

Answer (score 5):

Often certain repositories loading painfully slow is just a symptom of using a slow mirror.  The default mirrors for many regions are not the fastest (I know this is the case in China).

Changing your mirror is really easily done through the Software Sources GUI, you can open this window in two ways:

1. Open `Ubuntu Software Center` and click on `Software Sources` in the `Edit` menu.

or

2. Open a terminal (or type `alt-F2`) and run `software-properties-gtk`

When this window comes up you'll notice a drop down menu saying `Download From:` that selects your mirror.  Select the `Other` option from this menu.

[image: softwaresources]

In the new window that comes up click the <kbd>Select Best Server</kbd> button and this will test and automatically choose the fastest server for your location.

[image: select best server]

Hope this helps!

See also:

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Comment: Hmmm, I can't get the screenshot to capture the drop-down menu in action.  Don't know if I want to ask a question about this or file a bug...

Comment: Another possible bug I might file is that the `software-properties-gtk` program used to come up in the Unity dash when you typed `Software Sources`, but it no longer does...

Comment: Good answer adempewolff. As a first step this would be it. If it does not work then the accepted answer would be the solution. +1 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**apt-fast** works like **apt-get**, but downloads repository updates and packages in parallel.  See [this tutorial](http://notblog.org/faster-updates-with-apt-fast/) to learn how to use it.

Comment: Aptitude works in parallel. This is a nonsense solution