# How to resume download during apt-get install

Tags: software-installation, wget, android-studio

I am trying to install android studio via terminal on Ubuntu 12.04. However, every time the terminal gets to the download, the file download freezes at some point like this [image: screenshot]. Sometimes it freezes at 95%. I then have to start all over again. How do I resolve this such that on slight connection drop, the installation doesn't abort/hang. You can clearly see this is the 12th time am trying it from the extension in the download file.

Comment: When this happens, I just kill the command using `Ctrl +c` and then rerun it. It restarts from where it ended.

Comment: This might be useful: http://askubuntu.com/a/141523/360911

Comment: @RegisteredUser You are right!!! I just do the same. It is a kind of effective way to overcome such issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "resume" feature in `apt-get` (according to `man apt.conf`)  nor does dl.google.com support ftp (which would allow you to manually resume)

So the best you can do is:

1. to manually download the package from another location (work?) and then `cp /mnt/usb /var/cache/apt/archives`
2. set the `apt-get` time-out to a higher value by `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99apt.conf` and entering the following lines into it:

   `Acquire::http::Timeout "10";`

   `Acquire::ftp::Timeout "10";`

If the above doesn't make any sense, drop me a note @Fabby.

Answer (score 0):

You might [download that file manually](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.0.0-rc2/android-studio-ide-135.1611497-linux.zip). Then you might `unzip` it, and try to install it using `INSTALLION` guide.

Ps. then you need to get rid of the trash files: `find / -name android-studio-ide-135.1611497-linux.zip`