# Why apt-get update fail to connecting to dl.google.com?

Tags: networking, apt, updates, google-chrome

My Ubuntu is 14.04.

I try to update my packages by:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then it stuck at

```
100% [Connecting to dl.google.com (203.208.40.46)]
```

for several minutes. It is quite annoying.

I try to set a timeout for the connections [How to lower wait time for repository updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141513/how-to-lower-wait-time-for-repository-updates).

After several seconds, it failed and end the process.

```
Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                               

Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg       
  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2401:3800:4002:802::1005). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2401:3800:4002:802::1005 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to build.openvpn.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2401:3800:4002:802::1005). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2401:3800:4002:802::1005 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My location is China. I have Shadowsocks SOCKS5 system proxy and OpenVPN connecting to the same VPS server.
I have tried turning off them both separately and together, but it did not work.

I wonder why this happen and how do I tackle it?

---update---

I could download the provided by @JonasCz.

Comment: Are you sure your proxy / VPN is working correctly ? Both google.com and openvpn.net are failing, so my guess is that it's because of china's blocks on these. What do you get when you visit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg in a web browser ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I have this problem, I disable IPv6 in Ubuntu and that fix the problem, in order to do that, please follow these steps:

To disable IPv6, you have to open `/etc/sysctl.conf` using any text editor and add the following lines at the end:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

If IPv6 is still enabled, then the problem is that `sysctl.conf` is still not activated.

In that case, open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the command:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

The output will be very similar to these 3 lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After that, execute:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

If you see `1` in the output, then IPv6 has been successfully disabled.

```
1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This fixed my similar issue perfectly. Mine is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Nice! Good to hear that. =D

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you @SiqingYu

Comment: @galoget Hey guy, I found that disabling IPv6 slows down my apt download speed, so I enabled it again. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @SiqingYu, I always used the solution posted here, you can try this [Using IPv4 or IPv6 for apt](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-apt-get-with-ipv6-or-ipv4-transport-on-ubuntu-debian/), hope this works.

Comment: @galoget super cool solution , it works for me , could you explain the reason behind , why this change work ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the Google Chrome apt repository, and I resolved it with updating the repository key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

as stated at google official site:
https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/

Answer (score 0):

Have just found another option that only worked for me: after I updated Google's GPG key in my Ubuntu 18.04

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

software update went well:

```
sudo apt update
```