# Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80

Tags: apt, updates, google-chrome

Under Ubuntu 20.04, I am getting the oft-reported

```
Err:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2800:3f0:4002:802::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.172.78), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                             
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2800:3f0:4002:802::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.172.78), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The usual solution does not apply, since I already configured for 64-bit chrome:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

I thought perhaps I had wrong keys, so I tried ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1203382/226614))

```
$ curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to packages.cloud.google.com port 443: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

This is the only repo failing.
I didn't find other potential causes of the problem/solutions.

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: `curl -sL http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease` returns a proper `InRelease` file for me. Perhaps it was something temporary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (and strangely, for me), the culprit was a filter in my router for URL `http://www.youtube.com`.