# How to extend APT connection timeout?

Tags: apt, updates, firewall, timeout

I would like to extend the length of time that apt waits when downloading packages. Not the initial connection time as discussed in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141513/how-to-lower-wait-time-for-repository-updates) question, but extend the time it waits to finish.

The reason I would like to do this is that we have a firewall that scans everything incoming. What happens is that large packages are taking so long to get scanned by the incoming firewall that apt times out before the scanning completes. I've confirmed this with IT and they will add exceptions as necessary. I'd rather just have apt wait longer instead of requesting an exception every time (which is often).

For reference, this is the error I receive:

```
: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-dev_3.6.8-1~18.04.3_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the values in **apt.conf** as shown below for 10 seconds (use your preferred value, *of course*):

```
  Acquire::http::Timeout "10";
  Acquire::ftp::Timeout "10";
```