# Is it possible to accelerate downloads in Synaptic Manager?

Tags: synaptic, download-speed, apt-fast, axel

In Terminal that is possible by using apt-fast (using Axel).

But is it possible to put to work Axel and apt-fast in Synaptic Manager?

I found [this suggestion](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=100602.0), but I would not attempt it without the assistance from Ask Ubuntu :)

Comment: If you are afraid some procedure might break your system, just set up a virtual machine of ubuntu in virtualbox. Try the things there and if they work ok, you can then safely make it on your pc

Comment: Why edit synaptic when you can just use and apt-mirror.  Initial population of the mirror with apt-fast.

Comment: +1 for not attempting and seeking help :)

Comment: Cipricus: this method will not work with Ubuntu's Synaptic even if you tried -- see my edited answer.

Comment: @ aking1012 this is new for me. would you be so kind to provide some more info on apt-mirror, i have no idea what that is :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method in the forum thread (tricking Synaptic by renaming `apt-fast` to `apt-get` and vice versa) **will not work** with Ubuntu, because our Synaptic *does not use apt-get*. I've verified this by quickly looking at the source code, and also by moving `/usr/bin/apt-get` elsewhere -- Synaptic still works fine. Synaptic does reuse bits of code from *apt-get*, and it does use the actual *dpkg* binaries to perform installation, configuration, etc., but it does not use the `apt-get` binary.

#### Alternatives

- I would first recommend trying to find a fast, "networkically"-close mirror to try to max out speed. Please see the [command-line method in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line/141536#141536) for a very reliable way to do so.
- The second is to mark packages to install in Synaptic and then generate a download script from the *File* menu. This is a bash script with multiple `wget -c` entries, one for each deb file. Simply use `sed -i -e 's/wget -c/axel/g' scriptname` to use *axel* instead, run the script in an empty directory, and then do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Comment: @EliahKagan: See edit, this whole thing is a diversion ;) because Synaptic (on 12.04 at least) *does not use* the `apt-get` binary at all.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would do what LnxSlck said in his comment, set up a VM with Ubuntu and test there.  That would allow you to test without any real issue.  If it breaks, don't do it.  If it works, you can be semi-safe in the idea that it will work correctly without any true incident.

I tend to do this with every "test" i do with Ubuntu, so its a good practice if you dont want to explode your installation by accident.

Comment: izx said `Synaptic does not use apt-get`. well, if that is so, what is said on that forum I mentioned in the question is false because all that is based precisely on tweaking/twisting apt-get. therefore i would not bother testing that i guess.