# Why can't I install lib32gcc1?

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install Source Dedicated Server on Ubuntu Server 12.04 and every time I try to install `lib32gcc1`, I get

```
E: Package 'lib32gcc1' has no installation candidate
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I have tried running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and the error persists.

---

```
apt-cache policy lib32gcc1
lib32gcc1:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: (none)
Version table:
```

---

```
grep -r ^deb\ .*main /etc/apt/sources.list*    
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

---

As I *was* able to install the `openssh-server` package, here is the version table for that package:

```
apt-cache policy openssh-server
openssh-server:
Installed: 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1
Candidate: 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1
Version table:
*** 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1 0
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again

Comment: Can you provide the output of `grep -r ^deb\ .*main /etc/apt/sources.list*` and `apt-cache policy openssh-server`?

Answer (score 4):

The package [`lib32gcc1`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/lib32gcc1) is an `amd64` (64 bit) package only. You're running `i386` (32 bit) as can be seen from the output of `apt-cache policy openssh-server` in your question.

Now, either:

- Install `libgcc1` which is already 32-bit on your system:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libgcc1
  ```
- Install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu instead.

Comment: That's odd! I have the amd64 iso for 12.04... Hm. I'll try to redownload it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case that the mirror you're using is not up to date. Try changing the mirror to some other location.

**To do it using the command line:**

`apt-get` supports a mirror method that will automatically select a good mirror based on your location. Putting:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

on the top of your `/etc/apt/sources.list/` file is all that is needed.

You need to replace `YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE` with the name of your ubuntu version. e.g. `quantal` for Ubuntu 12.10, `precise` for Ubuntu 12.04, `oneiric` for 11.10, etc.

*Sources and further links:*

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/83046)
- [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39922/83046)

---

**To do it using the GUI:**

- Go to **Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources**.
- In the **Download From** dropdown menu, select *Server from United States* or *Main Server*.
- Try installing the package again.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this from command line? I'm running the server without a GUI.

Comment: updated the answer.