# Can not update Ubuntu - failed to fetch error

Tags: 12.04

When update crashes I got this message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://cran.at.r-project.org/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Looks like an external repository you've added is to blame. Remove it, and updating should work.

Comment: This might be a good way to deal with this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line/9035#9035

Comment: This isn't a PPA, it's just an external repository, but the answer to that question will fix this here too.

Answer (score 1):

I think your link is wrong, try this one

```
deb  http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
```