# "apt-get -f install" not working

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libunistring0:i386 python-numpy python-pygame deluge-gtk
  libsdl-mixer1.2 libgomp1:i386 liblapack3gf deluge-common libmikmod2
  libcroco3:i386 libgettextpo0:i386 libblas3gf libgfortran3 libsmpeg0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 212 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,722 B of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.37.45); however:
  Version of linux-image-generic on system is 3.2.0.40.48.
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.37.45); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 3.2.0.40.48.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please, try with some of the methods mentioned in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). If you find a solution (or not), tell us!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the repo mirror is out-of-sync.  Change mirrors or wait a day and see if your mirror caught up.

If you want to change mirrors try the tutorials in the answers to these questions:

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)
- [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line)