# Making mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com highly available

Tags: apt, mirrors

We're a distributed team, which is why our VMs use the Ubuntu `mirror://` setup. Our `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like the following:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt lucid main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt lucid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

This by itself is pretty amazing and very helpful for people who work in different locations — less *local* customization, etc. necessary. Fail-over in theory.

In day-to-day, this setup fails too often. I want to say 2-3 times this week.

Right now `mirrors.ubuntu.com` returns `ftp.uni-bayreuth.de` as my closet mirror. Unfortunately, it seems to be down.

This has been going on for a few hours and the mirror is hosted by volunteers at a university and today being a Friday, my hopes are low that this is getting corrected soon.

All talk, my questions are:

- Does anyone use this?
- How do you work around downtime? (my quick-fix is a shell script)
- How can I help to improve this situation?

Comment: Related: [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/39922/147044)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu - it is first time I read about netselect ...   8oþ

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Interesting tip! Cheers! I am trying to use the `mirror:` method which had the most updates in your thread. My problem is that whenever the fastest mirror fails, then there is no failover and I am stuck.

Comment: Is creating Your Own Ubuntu Mirror an option?

Comment: @Till Can you let me know if you can have your own mirror.

Comment: You may like to read [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror?lq=1#comment151249_37754)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate all the input on this question, but since no one came up with a simple solution which fit our circumstances, I decided to *fix* the problem myself.

I created a tool (specifically for Ubuntu) which I call `apt-spy2`.

The primary objective of this tool is to find a **working** mirror fast. Working is defined by that the mirror server is available and (hopefully :) up to date.

I make no assumptions about if the selected server is necessarily the closest and the fastest. I'm not doing any pings or GEO DNS tricks — but so far this works when something breaks.

How it works — in a nutshell:

1. I use http://mirrors.ubuntu.com or [launchpad's list of mirrors](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) to retrieve servers.
2. I do a simple check on each (for HTTP Response Status Code).
3. LBNL, I update `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

**Please note:** This assumes that people play nice and put additional mirrors (e.g. 3rd party repositories into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. But I guess that means there's room for improvement.

You can obtain this tool like so:

`$ [sudo] gem install apt-spy2`

The cli comes with `list`, `check`, `fix` and `help` (with extended information on how to use it).

I tried to document as much as possible in the project's [README](https://github.com/lagged/apt-spy2/blob/master/README.md).

The current version is a very conservative `0.5.0`.

The code is open source and the license is liberal. And I take all contributions.

Comment: Did you uploaded this to ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @Braiam *You can obtain this tool like so: sudo gem install apt-spy2*

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I'm asking if he uploaded it, since I'm interested in packaging something to Debian.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't package it up, but I would welcome it if someone did it. :)

Comment: @Braiam Btw, this is unlikely to work with Debian. ;( Only works with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

Personally I think that the best way to select the best Ubuntu repositories mirrors is to use the GUI method:

[image: download server]

Now, to improve the situation described in the question, you need to set some rules somehow. These rules must to act on `mirrors.ubuntu.com`. I can suggest some rules as follow:

- make a list of best/preferred mirrors; there are a lot of mirrors as you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), [here](http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/125252/147044)
- if you found a good mirror, add it to the list
- if a mirror was down or broken sometimes, it means that is not a good mirror and you should remove it from the list
- you can use [`netselect`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/netselect), [`apt-spy`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-spy) or [`apt-fast`](https://launchpad.net/apt-fast)
- and others, depending on your requirements.

Next, to see how you can work around, I can give you a method described step by step with three bash scripts examples. First script use the mirrors from the country you are in at the moment instead of `mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt` (for each country there is a text file with mirrors asociated; see http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/):

- In a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) run `mkdir -p bin` - this command will make a `bin` directory in your `home` folder if you don't already have it.
- After run `gedit ~/bin/change_sources.sh` - this will create the new file `change_sources.sh` in gedit.
- Copy and paste one of the next scripts in the new created file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0

if ! [ "`ping -c 1 google.com`" ]; then
    notify-send "No internet connection"
    exit 0  
fi

ip=$(curl -s 'http://ipecho.net/plain')
country=$(curl -s 'http://geoiplookup.net/geoapi.php?output=countrycode' \
    | awk '{ print toupper($2) }')
release=$(lsb_release -sc)

file="/etc/apt/sources.list"
old_file="/etc/apt/sources.list.old"

line=$(head -n 1 $file)
new_line="## Ubuntu Repos for $ip"

if [ "$line" == "$new_line" ] ; then
    exit 0
fi

cp -f $file $old_file

printf "$new_line
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/$country.txt $release main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/$country.txt $release-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/$country.txt $release-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/$country.txt $release-security main restricted universe multiverse
" > $file

notify-send "$file has been changed" "The old file has been put in $old_file"

exit 0
```

or, something similar to what can be found at http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0

if ! [ "`ping -c 1 google.com`" ]; then
    notify-send "No internet connection"
    exit 0  
fi

ip=$(curl -s 'http://ipecho.net/plain')
country=$(curl -s 'http://geoiplookup.net/geoapi.php?output=countrycode' \
    | awk '{ print tolower($2) }')
release=$(lsb_release -sc)

file="/etc/apt/sources.list"
old_file="/etc/apt/sources.list.old"

line=$(head -n 1 $file)
new_line="## Ubuntu Main Repos for $ip"

if [ "$line" == "$new_line" ] ; then
    exit 0
fi

cp -f $file $old_file

printf "$new_line
deb http://$country.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $release main restricted universe  multiverse
deb-src http://$country.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $release main restricted universe multiverse

## Ubuntu Update Repos for $ip
deb http://$country.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $release-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://$country.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $release-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://$country.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $release-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://$country.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $release-updates main restricted universe multiverse
" > $file

notify-send "$file has been changed" "The old file has been put in $old_file"

exit 0
```

or, a script using `netselect` (download from [here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/netselect/download), install instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-to-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)) as [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) explained verry nice in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/141536/147044):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0

if ! [ "`ping -c 1 google.com`" ]; then
    notify-send "No internet connection"
    exit 0  
fi

url=$(netselect \
    `wget -q -O- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors \
        | grep -P -B8 "statusUP|statusSIX" \
        | grep -o -P "(f|ht)tp.*\"" \
        | tr '"\n' '  '` \
    | awk '{print $2}')
release=$(lsb_release -sc)

if [ "$url" == "" ] ; then
    exit 0
fi

file="/etc/apt/sources.list"
old_file="/etc/apt/sources.list.old"

cp -f $file $old_file

printf "## Ubuntu Best Repos
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release main
deb $url $release main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $release-security restricted universe main multiverse
deb $url $release-updates restricted universe main multiverse
" > $file

notify-send "$file has been changed" "The old file has been put in $old_file"

exit 0
```

- Save the file and close it.
- Go back into terminal and run: `chmod +x ~/bin/change_sources.sh` - to grant execute access for the script.
- Just for test, to run your new script, type in terminal `~/bin/change_sources.sh`. It will give you an error, because you don't have the right to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`. So, use `sudo ~/bin/change_sources.sh`
- Edit the root user's crontab file using `sudo crontab -e` command and add the following line:

```bsh
@hourly /home/$USER/bin/change_sources.sh  
#change $USER with your user name
```

- I have set the cron job for every hour, but you can change as you wish or as you think is better. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron in this sense.
- Save the file and check the new crontab entry with `sudo crontab -l`.

> NOTE: To revert the changes made by this script, delete the cron job
>   and follow the indications from the picture above or use next command in terminal:
>
> ```
> cp -f /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```

From now, the file will be dynamically changed after it finds a change of the IP address.

It may not be the best solution, but, in my opinion, **a good solution can be given in this way like in the scripts above**.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. There are a few things. These VMs we have, they don't have a GUI — so the traditional method of point and click is not available and as I mentioned, I already have a shell script to fix up my mirrors. I know how to work around it if I have to. But my objective was to improve the `mirrors:` situation in general.

Comment: I guess I'd argue if a gui on linux can be ever considered the traditional way. :) But anyway: Your first script solves a problem, I don't have. The mirror syntax already gets my German mirrors, or U.S. or wherever people are. The second script uses the country mirrors — they seem to have the least bandwidth available (saw that in the archivemirrors list on launchpad), the third script assumes that a fast (or the closest) mirror is the indeed the best. Back to square one. I'm coding a small `apt-spy` script right now. Will update here later.

Comment: Last but not least — just to make sure: I am well aware of scriptable ways to work around mirrors.ubuntu.com being broken, or returning "broken" servers. But I'd like to fix that part instead of maintaining, scripts or a list of mirrors.

Comment: @Till Well, your question were "*How do you work around downtime?*" and "*How can I help to improve this situation?*". I showed how I work around and I suggested you how can you help to improve... Also, if you read my answer until the end, you can see that I am aware that "*It may not be the best solution, but I think that a good solution can be given in this way like in the scripts above*". Finally, if you are interested to fix/improve broken servers, this seems off-topic here and you should speak with the owners of those servers instead.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic. Various Canonical/Ubuntu people told me to add my question here. It's why I am here in the first place and I guess also why there is a bounty assigned.

Comment: @Till Yep, the question is good, but not as you reformulated it in these comments. Nobody will answer at "how to fix a broken mirror server" here as far as is not an administrator at the respective server.

Comment: I don't want to fix that server, I want to fix the selection algorithm and the lack of failover.

Comment: @Till So you need to set some rules somehow. These rules must act on `mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt`. And we came back at [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/319433/making-mirror-mirrors-ubuntu-com-highly-available/321591?noredirect=1#comment409479_321591).

Comment: The geoiplookup.net in the above script no longer works since it will now return a full html page, you have to use the geoiplookup XML API and parse the xml (or find some other service)

Answer (score 2):

There was this command at Debian 6.0.4 :

> apt-spy

This did the job to find the next closest available server automatic and to generate
a new sources.list

In Ubuntu this command seems not to exist ?

It still exists in Debian 7.0 wheezy :

https://launchpad.net/debian/wheezy/+source/apt-spy/+copyright

You can download your *.deb package here :

http://packages.debian.org/sid/apt-spy

... still searching for the sources ...

You obviously need Debian-7.0-Installation for to get the source-code after editing
sources-list with entry :

> deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main

Then after sudo apt-get update you would simply suck the code with :

> sudo apt-get source apt-spy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, apt-spy looks great indeed.

I'm not sure that works well. Every time I've installed debian stuff into ubuntu, it broke sooner or later due to other dependencies.

Comment: @Till - it is always something with bit more digging ... as soon as Linux is getting more demanding.

Comment: Build it for ubuntu: https://rubygems.org/gems/apt-spy2 and https://github.com/lagged/apt-spy2

Comment: @Till Do you mean: Build it ...! or Built it ...? - I look after next time - now is full-moon here and am groggy ...

Comment: you are quick !

Comment: @Till you can mail to my address in profile - null problemo - I send you output of terminal in mail ... now I need a bit rest until tommorrow. nightie.

Comment: `gem update apt-spy2` should fix all issues. I haven't checked email yet. Took a few days off, but just noticed a bug myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not using the solution you like, but setting up a local cache for the .deb files should be ideal when you download several MB of package (mostly of them I bet are the same) and since you are downloading from the same server, you might like to sacrifice a PC to make the cache and make the server less busy.

### Procedure

You should be able to set `apt-cacher` in a machine that have lots of space in the Hard Drive (you would need it). You can configure this using the [Apt-cacher server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server), but lets do a quick resume.

1. Install `apt-cacher`

   sudo apt-get install apt-cacher apache2
2. Edit `/etc/default/apt-cacher` and set the `autostart` value to 1, so your cache starts when the machine power up.
3. Restart apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
4. Test your cache using `http://ip-of.your.cache:3142/apt-cacher`.
5. You should allow host to use the cache, so edit `/etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf` and look for the line `allowed_hosts`. You can set subnets like `192.168.0.0/24` or just `*` for all hosts
6. **Look for a fast and reliable server around**. You could use `apt-spy` for this (this command could take hours since it also test the speed of each server).
7. In your clients you have two options:

   - set the `sources.list` as follow:

   deb http://ip-of.your.cache:3142/the.server.you.like/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe multiverse

   Change the `ip-of.your.cache` for the ip of your cache and `the.server.you.like` for the host name of the server you will be using. You can use several lines.

   - Or set apt to use a proxy: edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy` and add the line:

   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://ip-of.your.cache:3142";

Comment: If you would use apt-spy worldwide it would last a while ... but you can use this command with bordering to e.g. Europe by : apt-spy -d testing -a Europe

Comment: @dschinn1001 `-d testing` smells like Debian.

Comment: well then : apt-spy -a Europe

Comment: "downvote" ? - I did no downvote ? - it happens sometimes that I click by accident with my mouse - I never do down-vote with aim ! so voted you up ! thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up your own Ubuntu mirror.  That way updates will be local.

**apt-mirror needs a high speed internet connection and a lot of disk space**

Setting up your own Ubuntu mirror is very easy by using apt-mirror.

1) go into the apt-mirror repository. Back up your sources.list file like so:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
```

2) Edit the sources.list file like so:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

3) And insert the following on a new line:

```
deb http://apt-mirror.sourceforge.net/ apt-mirror
```

4) Let’s update the package index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

5) And install apt-mirror

```
sudo apt-get install apt-mirror
```

6) Apt-mirror is now set up so let’s tell it what servers to mirror:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/mirror.list /etc/apt/mirror.list.old
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

The default configuration will put your downloaded files in the /var/spool/apt-mirror folder. Here’s how the mirror.list file looks like:

```
############# config ##################
#
set base_path /media/silo/repo
#
# if you change the base path you must create the directories below with write privlages
#
# set mirror_path $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path $base_path/skel
# set var_path $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch <running host architecture>
set nthreads 20
set tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid -updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid -backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid -security main restricted universe multiverse
clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

this only mirrors binary packages but if you want source packages, you should insert the appropriate lines. They usually take the form:

```
deb-src http://gh.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
```

7) Now, run `apt-mirror`. This is going to take quite a while.  Don’t worry if you cannot download all the files in one go, `apt-mirror` can resume downloads (kill it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key combination and re-run it when you want to continue). Okay, run apt-mirror like so:

```
sudo apt-mirror /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

Also check out [How To Create A Local Debian/Ubuntu Mirror With apt-mirror](http://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror)

<sup>Source:[Use Apt-mirror to Create Your Own Ubuntu Mirror](http://odzangba.wordpress.com/2007/12/24/use-apt-mirror-to-create-your-own-ubuntu-mirror/)</sup>

Comment: If memory serves me right, `apt-mirror` is available in ubuntu repositories.

Comment: BTW, make sure to note the need of lots of space in the HD to download a complete mirror ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it's a great resource for setting up a mirror and I've considered that, but then I'd need this setuo in at least 3 different locations. I know I am picky here, but I still feel that `mirrors.ubuntu.com` ought to work. :)

Comment: @till `mirrors.ubuntu.com` will never resolve `mirrors.ubuntu.com`, but a server that is nearest to you. Problem is that server it resolve is an unreliable one. Your better play is using a reliable server from the official list.

Comment: @Braiam any idea why unreliable mirrors are returned by it then?

Comment: @Till because of your physical location. You may select a reliable mirror manually instead of depending of automatic mirrors. These were intended for people that travels too much (using their portables pc's, aka laptops), no for statics located systems.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Python script called [apt-select](https://github.com/jblakeman/apt-select) to serve as a CLI alternative to the GUI method.

The script queries each mirror via TCP, prints to stdout mirrors with the lowest latency, and generates a new `sources.list` file.  There are also multiple options that allow you to choose from a list of ranked mirrors, and retrieve information such as when the mirror was last updated and its bandwidth capacity.