# HTTP or FTP in sources.list?

Tags: repository, software-sources, ftp, https

Which protocols are better to use in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? HTTP or FTP?

For example:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe restricted multiverse
```

or:

```
deb ftp://ftp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: There is similar question exists on another SE site, hope that helps .. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30210/should-i-use-http-or-ftp-links-in-apt-sources-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use HTTP. In this sense I found [this nice answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30211/37944):

> You're not going to save much time using one over the other, but if efficiency is what you care about, use HTTP. An FTP client has to send a username and password and receive acknowledgments for those, and then issue several commands to set up the file transfer and receive acks for those, too. All this back and forth magnifies the effect of network latency; with 100-200ms ping times to the server you could waste a second setting up the transfer. With HTTP, the client opens the connection, sends one command and the file transfer starts immediately.
>
> <sup>(Thanks to [Kyle Jones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14259/kyle-jones) for this answer)</sup>

Also, I will add that I personally always use the best server found by Ubuntu (in **System Settings...** → **Software & Updates** → **Ubuntu Software** tab, and choose **Othher...**):

[image: choose server]

You may be also interested by:

- [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39922/147044)
- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/147044)
- [Making mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com highly available](https://askubuntu.com/q/319433/147044)