# Could not connect to bd.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (116.193.170.18), connection timed out

Tags: apt, updates

I'm trying to update my system using `apt-get`, but it's giving me this error

```
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg       
  Could not connect to bd.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (116.193.170.18), connection timed out
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to bd.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to bd.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Could not connect to bd.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (116.193.170.18), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to bd.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to bd.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am not a Ubuntu master but I can understand this is not a computer error. Any clues on how to fix it?

Comment: This happens when my internet is down. Is your internet working?

Comment: yes, working. Its just happening with one of the update.
BTW, how to post this if i dont have internet?

Comment: Your configured Ubuntu archive mirror (`bd.archive.ubuntu.com`) appears to be down. Select another mirror. Please refer to [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/39922/88802) and [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](http://askubuntu.com/q/37753/88802) on how to do that.

Comment: Probably that server (bd.archive.ubuntu.com) is having some problems. You can go to "Software & Updates" (in 13.04) and choose adifferent server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The server `bd.archive.ubuntu.com` is just not responding right now. Try another server.

Go to **System Settings**, and click on *Software and Updates*. On the first tab, locate the dropdown labelled *Download from* and choose another location for your downloads, or *Main Server*.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to smack yourself in the head over this but you probably aren't connected to the Internet.

If that is not true then you'll want to find a better repository to grab your packages from (because you're timing out to the one you have). Fortunately, Ubuntu has your back here. Changing the source server you use is really easy and automatic. Follow these instructions (for Gnome):

- Open up System|Administration|Software Sources, and then select the "Download from: "Other".
- Click on "Select Best Server". That will go through all of the servers/mirrors and ping each one.
- It will then come back and tell you which one it got the best response from.

In Kubuntu it's a little different:

- Open the application Muon Software Center (use the search on the start  menu if you're having trouble finding it)
- In the settings menu select 'Configure Software Sources'.
- In the dialog you'll see a 'Download From...' dropdown. Use this to select a different repository.

A full tutorial is available on this subject in case you are having troubles with this: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories?action=show&redirect=AddingRepositoriesHowto