# How to find fastest mirror from given list?

Tags: software-recommendation

I know that [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39922/184942) exists, but it deals only with mirrors for ubuntu sources.

I want a application/script/command which would find the best mirror/server from a given list, which may or may not be related to Ubuntu.

For example https://www.archlinux.org/download/ gives a list of Arch Linux mirrors. Similarly many softwares have multiple mirrors. I want to find the best mirror from the given list. I am ready to add the mirrors one by one into some script/app/command.

If possible, the script/app/command should find the mirror which gives highest speed, rather than one that is closest.

Comment: Fastest or nearest? Because fastest can only be tested with speed test, that downloads a file out all servers, while nearest can be done with pings/traceroute.

Comment: @braiam fastest is prefered.

Comment: Do you need a command line application or can be GUI?

Comment: I would recommend you to ask instead in [softwarerecs.se]