# 13.10 to 14.04 upgrade "Failed to fetch..."

Tags: upgrade

When i tried to upgrade, the following msg appears and the upgradation stopes. Please help.
//
Failed to fetch 
http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/highlight.js/libjs-highlight_7.4+ds-1_all.deb 
404 Not Found [IP: xxx.xx.xxx.xx xx] 
//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your repository server. You can follow these methods

- [How do I change mirrors in Ubuntu Server from regional to main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine
- [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line)