# Automatizing apt-mirrors selection

Tags: networking, updates, downloads, apt-mirror

I have `ubuntu 15.04` on my PC and I have issues everytime I make an update or I install packets mirrors are so slow and it's almost impossible to download with an average speed of 20 KB/s.

I've tried to switch to other mirrors and test them until I find one that boosts up the download speed (all the servers have the same speed most of the time) but this method is a real time wasting one.

How can I automatize the selection of the fastest mirror for apt  ? is there a script to ping mirrors and select the best one temporary ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I've tried the `netselect` based solution, it's not what I'm looking for as it's selects a mirror by latency ( the closest one ) not the one with better bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/141536/38557.  It's a bit long but should do exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I saw this but netselect will rank mirrors by to latency not according to their download speed.