# Attempting to install packages - stuck connecting to security.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, security

I just recently built a new computer using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have been attempting to install all different kinds of packages (Google Chrome and Steam mainly). Whenever I attempt to run (sudo apt-get update) it runs up until the point of:

```
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::21)]
```

and it just stays there.... Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

Could be just a slow connection ... to find the fastest Ubuntu server :

```
System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software
```

click on

```
Download from :  choose Other ...
```

choose

```
Select Best Server
```

let the test run for a few seconds while it probes to discover the answer ... then

```
Choose Server
```

let us know if this helps

Comment: How do you do this from the CLI?

Comment: @FakeName find fastest server from cli  https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line