# Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

Tags: apt, 16.04, updates

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This morning when I ran `sudo apt-get update`, I encountered the following error:

```
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've checked the internet for an answer. Although I did find a few similar posts, none of the solution works for me. One of the interesting solution I tried was:

The simplest solution is to do the following two steps:

1- Backup your sources list -> sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup

2- Open the sources file "/etc/apt/sources.list" Rename all the instances of us.archive or archive in `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` to

`http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`

Also do the same for the `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages`

3- Run sudo apt-get update after doing the above.

Guess what.. didn't work. Infact it threw more errors:

```
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please help.

**EDIT:**

Here is my original sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you select the fastest mirror from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @mikewhatever The duplicate is not valid - the OP's issue is not selection of the 'fastest mirror', but rather they tried to fix a Lucid repository warning issue and in the process broke their Xenial setup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've made a few grave errors here.

First, you are running 16.04.  That means you can't blindly replace the normal archive mirror with `old-releases`.  This is why you currently get the errors you get about Xenial repos missing.

Secondly, you are still trying to draw from the Lucid repository.  That won't help you, because a good portion of the items in the Lucid repository will not work in Xenial or were removed from the repos for various reasons, or were superseded by updated versions.  And, the instructions you followed for old releases *only* applies to the Lucid repository line you had in your configs.

---

Here's how to fix the problems you're having.

1. Go through `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and start by replacing all the `old-releases.ubuntu.com` entries with your original mirror, `us.archive.ubuntu.com`.
2. Find the lines that reference `lucid` and either comment them out, or use `old-releases.ubuntu.com` **only for that repository**.

   If you don't know which entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` has this 'lucid' entry, then run this command from `/etc/apt/`:  `grep -r -i lucid /etc/apt/`; it will identify the files containing the word 'lucid'
3. `sudo apt-get update` and similar commands should now work without issue.

I would strongly recommend commenting out the Lucid repositories, as they are end of life as well, and unless you *really* need something from them, you should not be keeping them activated.

Comment: I cannot findany line referencing `lucid`.  I've edited the question and added my `sources.list`. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Check everywhere in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ as well.  *Somewhere* you have Lucid, or you would not have gotten the error you did at first.  Consider just trying an `apt-get update` too to see if the error is now resolved.  (use `grep -r -i lucid /etc/apt/` to find any Lucid references)

Comment: found it. There were 2 references inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/alternative_Repo.list`. After commenting'em out the errors are gone now.