# Package authentication errors in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, grub2, package-management, updates

Trying to update my 16.04 desktop install, I get package authentication errors for grub (details below). I also get authentication errors when trying to install other packages (sound-juicer and dependencies). This problem is referenced here for multiple versions of Ubuntu:

[Why am I getting authentication errors for packages from an Ubuntu repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository)

However none of the mentioned solutions works for me. Any suggestions?

======

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml
Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
- open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

When I subsequently run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub2-common
  grub-common
```

Comment: Sorry don't know the error but, I suspect after fixing `sudo apt update` error then `sudo apt upgrade` error will dissappear. If this solves your problem let us know: https://askubuntu.com/questions/840036/failed-to-fetch-http-us-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-dists-lucid-main-source-sour/840044

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I misunderstood one of the error messages quoted above, and one of the solutions at the article I referenced did indeed work:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ...
```

Thank you, WinEunuuchs2Unix. My bad.