# Default download server in Software & Updates

Tags: server, updates, 20.04, mirrors

Noob question, why the default Download server in Software & Updates is United States when my location is Singapore?

Furthermore, when I click "Other" and attempt to "Select the best server", I am almost always pointed to a US server, or sometimes a European one, but never an Asian one (and there are actually a few in Singapore).

Many thanks!

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the network speed. To check the speed of mirrors yourself, you can run

```
curl -s http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt | xargs -n1 -I {} sh -c 'echo `curl -r 0-102400 -s -w %{speed_download} -o /dev/null {}/ls-lR.gz` {}' |sort -g -r
```

This command is taken from @Kandy's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/719551/1107236

Comment: Should also be able to pick a server you want from the list, but it might not fastest, or try finding best server at different times of day, might have done test when server was busy.

Comment: Yeah that I get, but still why does the default show as United States?