# Ubuntu is slow - apt-get update is slow, the boot time is slow, etc

Tags: boot, 16.04, apt, server

Since Thursday, my Ubuntu 16.04.7 server has been extremely sluggish, even when the load is below 1.0.

apt-get update and apt-get upgrade are both extremely slow. The boot time also takes ages.

I have PHP running on the server and scripts are also taking much longer to execute, even though there are barely any requests coming in.

Output of the top results from **systemd-analyze blame**:

```
2min 11.015s apt-daily.service
1min 56.993s cloud-init-local.service
1min 12.026s console-setup.service
1min 8.095s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1min 6.282s dev-vda1.device
1min 649ms cloud-init.service
50.921s apparmor.service
50.255s cloud-config.service
44.707s cloud-final.service
32.721s mysql.service
27.685s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
20.327s systemd-update-utmp.service
17.572s snapd.service
11.468s boot-efi.mount
11.051s resolvconf.service
10.486s nginx.service
10.369s networking.service
10.203s certbot.service
```

Output of critical-chain:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3rdK.png)

Has anyone got an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you please edit your post with results for running SMART data and tests on the drive that you are using please? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a faster mirror for apt updates? [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/719551/167115) provides a method of determining the fastest mirror. Change `head -1` to `head -3` to show the top 3 fastest mirrors and run the command multiple times to get a more accurate reading. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to use the desired mirror instead of the default.

Comment: Also, give the command a little while to run as it has to go through all of the mirrors.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.